# Text larger on iphone

Tags: iphone

I have a scrolling footer. The scrolling area has the same size in pixels assigned to it as its static title 'News Tweets':
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/pp-new/

On my computer and ipad everything is fine, but on an iphone the scrolling area of the text is larger. As it all has the same CSS I can't figure out why this is happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile WebKit sometimes resizes text, presumably to make it easier to read on the small screen. You can adjust or disable this behavior through the [`-webkit-text-size-adjust` CSS property](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-text-size-adjust).